# Python patch a classmethod under a chain of classes

Tags: python

In the following how to patch a method where it is chained in so many classes.
Trying this patch in `class report exec function`. What is the right way to patch this.The solution below is not working .what is the issue here?and how to make it work.

This is the line that i want to patch `ipBuilder.calc_avg = self.calc_avg`

```
#repo/report_builder.py

from repo.calc import Tree

class report(object):
    def calc_avg(self, data):
        return(data.get('inet_addr'))

    def exec(self):
        from repo.builder import ipbuilder
        ipBuilder.calc_avg = self.calc_avg  ## how to achieve this patch
        Tree().exec()

report().exec()

#repo/calc.py
from repo.ipbuilder import Factory
class Tree():
    def exec(self,data):
        ip_new = data.get('ip_new')
        cntxt = data.get('cntxt')
        Factory.getBuilder(ip_new).with_context(cntxt).calc_avg(data)

#repo/ipbuilder.py
from repo.builder import ipBuilder
class Factory(object):
    def init(self):
        self.toclass = {'ip' : ipBuilder
            }
    @classmethod
    def getBuilder(cls, buildercls):
        ipclass = cls.__inst.toclass(buildercls)
        return ipclass()

#repo/builder.py
class ipbuilder(object):
    def calc_avg(self,data):
        data = some_calc()
        return data
```

Comment: As much as I want to help you, it is hard to understand what is your goal here, this is not very idiomatic in Python. The fact that you are not following PEP-8 conventions does not help. Some things you can do to improve your question: 1) provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (your current example seems to have more than the minimum required to answer the question). 2) Try to ask about the original problem you are trying to ask instead of asking how to implement the solution you devised (XY problem).

Comment: The objective here is to patch the method as mentioned in the above code

Comment: I apologize if my comment sounded condescending, I can assure you I'm trying to help. Please understand the answer you need is not necessarily the answer you want. What problem are you trying to solve by patching the class? Monkey-patching is frowned upon in Python so if we understand what your are trying to accomplish we can suggest a "pythonic" version.

Comment: Wrong design (and a really brittle one actually).

Comment: @Naveen design changes do not need to be disruptive, and in this case it's quite easy to come with a perfectly backward-compatible sane solution, cf my answer.

Comment: @Naveen oh and yes whilee we're at it: I answered the question because a better solution was possible, but usually I would have voted to close your question because it doesn't contains all the required informations - specifically, "is not working" is a totally useless description of a problem -, so next time please make sure you post __all_ relevant informations: 1/ a minimal reproducible example (we should be able to copy-paste and run you code snippet) and 2/ an exact description of the issue (full error message AND traceback, or results you got and why they are wrong).

Comment: IOW : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While monkeypatching can sometimes be a real life-saver, it's not without issues and should really be considered as  a last resort momentary Q&D fix.

Here you obviously have the hand on the whole code, so the proper solution here is to change the code for a saner design, in this case the "strategy" pattern (implemented the most pythonic way: as a mere callable).

It's actually a very small and totally backward compatible change:

```
# NB: code reorganized in a more meaningfull way and names changed to comply with pep08.
# I also added missing params in calls etc, assuming
# those were only forgotten when you tried to reduce 
# your snippet to the relevant part

class Factory(object):
    def init(self):
        self.toclass = {'ip' : ipBuilder}

    @classmethod
    def getBuilder(cls, builderclsname):
        ipclass = cls.toclass[builderclsname]
        return ipclass()

class IpBuilder(object):

    # here we add an optional `calc_strategy` 
    # arg that defaults to the original `some_calc`
    # function so existing code is not impacted

    def calc_avg(self, data, calc_strategy=None):
        if calc_strategy is None:
            calc_strategy = some_calc
        return calc_strategy(data)


class Tree(object):
    # we have to pass the `calc_strategy` down
    # the call chain obviously...
    def exec(self, data, calc_strategy=None):
        ip_new = data.get('ip_new')
        cntxt = data.get('cntxt')
        builder = Factory.getBuilder(ip_new).with_context(cntxt)  
        return builder.calc_avg(data, calc_strategy=calc_strategy)


class Report(object):
    def calc_avg(self, data):
        return(data.get('inet_addr'))

    def exec(self):
        # and finally we pass our own calc_strategy here
        return Tree().exec(calc_strategy=self.calc_avg)


Report().exec(somedata)
```

NB: this solution is of course and obviously based on what code you provided, and depending on the rest of the code there might (or not) be a more appropriate way to setup and pass the "strategy" callable, but the principle would remain the same.

As to why monkeypatching is a very bad idea here: since you have to monkeypatch the class itself (not an instance of it), you are actually changing the behaviour for all instances of the class within the current process, so all calls to `ipbuilder.calc_avg` happening after you setup the monkeypatch will now use the monkeypatched version.

If this only ever happens in a short-running process without any concurrency and this is the one and only (direct or indirect) call to `ipbuilder.calc_avg` then it's not an issue by itself, **but** it's still brittle as any (voluntary or accidental) reuse of this code snippet in another context will start breaking your code in the most unexpected ways and in a complex system tracing such issues can quickly become a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for the patch explanation

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide arguments to multiple methods

```py
ipBuilder.calc_avg = self.calc_avg
#self.calc_avg requires arguments as it's a method of report
#same for Tree.exec()
```

As written in Tree class

```java
Factory.getBuilder(ip_new).with_context(cntxt).calc_avg(data)
```

Parameters are provides